# Next.js (React.js), with Node.js server Socket.io client multiple IDs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, socket.io

I'm having an issue where my React app is outputting the same one ID on every page that it loads, where as Backend Node.js Socket.io server is outputting multiple client IDs whenever I change route in my app...

Server:

```
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("client connected: ", socket.id);

  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    console.log("disconnect", reason);
  });
});
```

App.js:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect", socket.id);

    return () => {
      socket.off("connect");
      socket.off("disconnect");
    };
  }, []);
```

Socket.ts:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOCKET_IO_URL}`);
socket.on("connect", () => console.log("socket_id", socket.id));
export default socket;
```

server.js (backend - websocket)

```
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("client connected: ", socket.id);

  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    console.log("disconnect", reason);
  });});
```

[image: Backend server logs]

[image: Frontend logs]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, socket.io server sometimes generates a new id due reconnections or others things:

https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-socket-instance/#socketid

So if you are planning keep the same id, i disencourage you.

Well, but looks you are wondering about fast recriation of ids. React is rendering according state changes, so create a stateless connection inside some component cause this behaviour. Yon can choose a lot of solutions but, i will present you a solution extensible, ease to mantain and deliver to componets the role of subscribe and unsubscribe to itself listeners, this sounds better than have a global listeners declaration :D

**1. Create Socket Context**
We will use `useContext` hook to provide SocketContext to entire app.

Create a file in **context/socket.js**:

```
import React from "react"
import socketio from "socket.io-client"
import { SOCKET_URL } from "config"

export const socket = socketio.connect(SOCKET_URL)
export const SocketContext = React.createContext()
```

**2. Use socket context and provide a value**
Add SocketContext provider at the root of your project or at the largest scope where socket is used:

```
import {SocketContext, socket} from 'context/socket';
import Child from 'components/Child';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
      <Child />
      <Child />
      ...
    </SocketContext.Provider
  );
};
```

**3. Now you can use socket in any child component**
For example, in GrandChild component, you can use socket like this:

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useCallback, useEffect} from 'react';
import {SocketContext} from 'context/socket';

const GrandChild = ({userId}) => {

  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

  const [joined, setJoined] = useState(false);

  const handleInviteAccepted = useCallback(() => {
    setJoined(true);
  }, []);

  const handleJoinChat = useCallback(() => {
    socket.emit("SEND_JOIN_REQUEST");
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    // as soon as the component is mounted, do the following tasks:

    // emit USER_ONLINE event
    socket.emit("USER_ONLINE", userId); 

    // subscribe to socket events
    socket.on("JOIN_REQUEST_ACCEPTED", handleInviteAccepted); 

    return () => {
      // before the component is destroyed
      // unbind all event handlers used in this component
      socket.off("JOIN_REQUEST_ACCEPTED", handleInviteAccepted);
    };
  }, [socket, userId, handleInviteAccepted]);

  return (
    <div>
      { joined ? (
        <p>Click the button to send a request to join chat!</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Congratulations! You are accepted to join chat!</p>
      ) }
      <button onClick={handleJoinChat}>
        Join Chat
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**What is `useContext`?**

useContext provides a React way to use global state,
You can use context in any child component,
Context values are states. React notices their change and triggers re-render.

**What is `useCallback`? Why did you put every handlers inside `useCallback`?**
`useCallback` prevents reassigning whenever there is state update
Functions will be reassigned only when elements in the second argument are updated

More reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecallback.asp

This nice tutorial has obtained in:
https://dev.to/bravemaster619/how-to-use-socket-io-client-correctly-in-react-app-o65

Comment: Thank you for extended answer it clears it up a lot. I have 1 more question, you mentioned I should not use socket id on clients. How do you manage to send the response from server to specific user then?

Comment: Nice question, my favorite approach is subscribe client to a private listener (AKA private channel), where only this specific client will handle their own payload. You can create a listener like this socket.on('private-'+uuid_client,(...)) so in server side when you need send to a specific client just... io.emit('private-'+uuid_client,{...}). There are others approaches, but this is under your control and not depends on a volatile socket.id

Comment: I just want to clarify one more thing, even with using context I am connecting to backend WebSocket whenever any of the state on my frontend changes. 
I will differentiate between the connections by adding the users to their private channels (channel_uuid). Is that correct?

Comment: You should keep data about client deep inside your application, so access them as you need across other states changes, redux can be a nice place to achieve, this and react's context itlself handle it. So keep on mind, no matters how your socket conn is breaked or reconnected, with strategies of how you access the data which wrap all whole application you will ever get back client_uuid to subscribe, unsubscribe, close app, reopen. With data management client_uuid or another stuffs always be there for you.